# Custom cross-browser scrollbar without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

CSS scrollbar styling isn't fully supported in all major browsers, so I was wondering, how could it be achieved without the use of jQuery.

Is there a light JS for something like this?

I think, that it's not very effective to use jQuery because of a scrollbar.

looking for pure **javaScript** solution without depending any frameworks like jQuery

Comment: it is very effective. efficient? that depends on how you look at it. Adding milliseconds of load time is probably a negligible expense. Now, if jQuery took 5 seconds to load and process scrollbars then you may have an argument

Comment: If the plugins that are available, like jScrollbar, does'nt suit your needs, write your own, but recreating the scroll functionality is probably a lot more involved than you think.

Comment: @KaiQing - So have I, and it's a shitload of more work than just creating an element that slides inside another element.

Comment: So you're saying that it's much better to use jQuery, if I don't want to spend hours or days trying to figure it out on my own.

Comment: It's *never* better to use jQuery.